# MongoDB C# Array index or indexing inner items of arrays

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I use a dynamic array storage key, value, type in dynamicArray. MongoDB/C# generaly use an index of the array like db.contents.ensureIndex ( { dynamicArray : 1 } ). Storing more than 30 or 40 elements are generating a big information to index using this method. Exist another way to index not the complete array but items key of this array limiting the index storage. Something like -> Index key:Name, Index key:City and not all.

```
dynamicArray:
{
    item : { Key: "Name", Value: "Peter", Type:String }
    item : { Key: "Age", Value: "18", Type:int }
    item : { Key: "City", Value: "San Jose", Type:String }
    ...30 to 40 items.
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Something like -> Index key:Name, Index key:City and not all.

You cannot do this specifically, you cannot index on the value of key.

**One Solution**

However, you can index on items in an array.

Let's assume that your data looks like this:

```
items:
  [
       { Key: "Name", Value: "Peter", Type:String },
       { Key: "Age", Value: "18", Type:int },
       { Key: "City", Value: "San Jose", Type:String },
       ...30 to 40 items.
  ]
```

You would do the following to create an index on `items.Key`:

```
 db.foo.ensureIndex( { 'items.Key' } )
```

When you do the following you will use the index:

```
 db.foo.find( { 'items.Key' : "City", 'items.value' : "San Jose" } )
```

This will narrow the search to only those items that have `Key = "City"`. If this is everything, then this probably won't help.

**Alternate solution**

Why is `items` an array? Can you not structure data like this:

```
items:
  {
       "Name" : { Value: "Peter", Type:String },
       "Age" : { Value: "18", Type:int },
       "City" : { Value: "San Jose", Type:String },
       ...30 to 40 items.
  }
```

Now you can index on `items.City.Value`, which is what you were looking for in the first place. This also makes the data structure quite a bit smaller.

Depending on the nature of your data, you may also want to look at [sparse indexes](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Indexes#Indexes-SparseIndexes) to help control the size of your index.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but mongoDB doesn't allow to index partly by condition.

Comment: Obviously this is old, but mongoDb does support conditional indexes on arrays http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-multikey/