# MongoDB C# - Index field in array

Tags: c#, mongodb

With the following structure:

```
class A
{
    ...
    List<B> L;
}

class B
{
    ...
    string S;
}
```

and a collection of objects A, is it possible to create an index on the S fields?

---

Update:
The solution proposed in the comments does NOT work:

```
public class A
{
    public List<B> L;
    public A()
    {
        L = new List<B>();
    }
}

public class B
{
    public string S;
}
```

and index creation:

```
MongoCollection.Indexes.CreateOne(new BsonDocument {{ "B.S", 1}});
```

yields:

[image]

only the _id field gets indexed, but B.S is not.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create MongoDB MultiKey index on attribute of items in an array .NET Driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44070496/how-to-create-mongodb-multikey-index-on-attribute-of-items-in-an-array-net-driv)

Comment: I saw this one, but I don't see how my question relates to multi-key

Comment: I assume you plan to ignore the fact that it shows you how to index an array item's value then?: `await collection.Indexes.CreateOneAsync(new BsonDocument {{"name", 1}, {"bars.key", 1}});`

Comment: Or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5078333/mongodb-c-sharp-array-index-or-indexing-inner-items-of-arrays) also shows the same thing albeit for an older version.

Comment: You mean that new BsonDocument {{"B.S", 1}} would work?

Comment: `"L.S": 1` would work.

Comment: ok, awesome! I am right to believe that since that other post was written there is still no Linq solution?

Comment: It may have been fixed since last year, but in my last test I found that `L[-1].S` didn't work to create an index, so to the best of my knowledge there isn't currently a LINQ solution.

Answer (score 2):

The last time I checked (mid-late last year), `a => a.L[-1].S` syntax did not work to create an index, so I do not believe there is a LINQ way of achieving this at the moment.

In my own project, I'm using code similar to this:

```
myCollection.Indexes
    .CreateOne(Builders<A>.IndexKeys
        .Ascending("L.S"));
```

This will create an index using the array items.

Comment: Can you check that the index is really built? on my end when I look I don't see an index created on that collection (using Studio 3T)

Comment: You tried `B.S`, not `L.S` - B is your class name, not your property name.

Comment: I just found my own answer from a Google search whilst looking for something else.